# How do I capture Mac trackpad events and gestures so that they don't have their usual effects?

Tags: macos, trackpad

I'm writing a an app that that does midi synthesis from the trackpad ([Multitouch Midi](https://www.jefftk.com/multitouch_midi)) and one of the annoying things is that while it's running the actions you're taking are being interpreted both to create sound but also to do whatever else they would normally do, like trigger Expose.

I'd like to keep those events from going to other programs, and handle all trackpad input myself until the user presses a key.  This is like what Preview's "Create Signature" uses:

[image]

While preview is in this mode, it captures all trackpad events, keeping them from doing whatever they would normally do, until the user presses a key.

How does it do that?